# Looking for LinkedIn API product to fetch user work experience

Tags: react-native, linkedin-api

I am looking for the specific LinkedIn API product that facilitates the retrieval of work experience information and the process to enable it within my app. And also looking for fetching companies name registered with linkedin.
#linkedin #linkedinAPI